# Find exec command not executed in Crontab

Tags: linux

I have a command defined in crontab:

```
 40 12 * * * /bin/find /tmp/zzz -type f -name `date -d '-1 day' '+server.log.%Y-%m-%d'` -exec echo {} \;
```

However, I don't see this command being executed at the specified time. I searched around, and I think it is because ';'(semi-colon) does not work well with cron. if so, how do I achieve this purpose ( i.e. using find command with -exec option)?

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that invalidates the existing answers. I've rolled back your edit, if you have a follow up question please add a new one.

Comment: ok, sorry, i can delete this question if you want

Comment: This is not respectful for people answering your question and future readers having this issue

Answer (score 2):

No, the `%` need to be escaped in `cron`, so:

```
 40 12 * * * /bin/find /tmp/zzz -type f -name `date -d '-1 day' '+server.log.\%Y-\%m-\%d'` -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: thank you so much for your comments, it does help me move forward! however, seeing new issues after this...